# Check for integrability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Check as for the the integrability the following function $$g(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{|x|^a}, a>0$$

How could we do this?? Do we have to check if $g \in L^1$. But at which space??

Comment: Presumably the measure space is $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So do we have to calculate the integral of this function on R?? @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that $g\in L^1$, note that
$$
\|g\|_{L^1}=2\int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{-x^2}x^{-a}\,\mathrm dx = \Gamma\left(\frac{1-a}{2}\right),
$$
hence you need $0<a<1$ for the integral to converge (provided you "know" about the gamma function).

EDIT: The last equality can be seen using the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: So we conclude that the function is integrable when 0<a<1 right?? When we have the function $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ do we have to do the following? $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}| \frac{\sin x}{x}|\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx$$ is it correct so far?? How do we continue??

Comment: Yes, the $g$ is integrable provided $0<a<1$. For the function $f(x)=\operatorname{sinc}x$ you should bound its $L^1$ norm from below by the harmonic series to see that it diverges. Your estimate gives the upper bound $\infty$ and does not help.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)